# Not able to clone git repo hosted on Windows Server 2012

Tags: git, iis, github, clone, bonobo

I have hosted the Bonobo Git Server(https://bonobogitserver.com/) on IIS8 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard machine(named myhostserver); created a repository(bare) on this server (myrepo.git).

I am able clone this repo on the server itself via command

**git clone**
http://admin@localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/myrepo.git

Also, when I access the URL to this server (http://myhostserver/Bonobo.Git.Server) from another machine on LAN, I can login as well as see the repo (myrepo). It shows the URL to the repo as 
http://admin@myhostserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/myrepo.git.

But when I attempt to clone this repo (on the current machine on the LAN) via command:

**git clone**
[enter link description here](http://admin@myhostserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/myrepo.git)
, the command fails with output: **fatal:

**git clone** http://admin@myhostserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/myrepo/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?**

How can I solve this problem?